# Recommendation on win32 assembly reader

Tags: winapi, assembly

I'm a beginner to reading assembly language and I'm looking for a good assembly reader for win32, which one do you recommend?

Comment: Assembly reader as in a Disassembler dump utility?

Comment: @tommieb75 Yes, so i can view the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are much better off writing your own assembly code, best way to learn.  But you can get reams of inscrutable assembly code from [dumpbin.exe /disasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtf7fdaz.aspx) or [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/).